# Why Reject of Promise giving undefined error?

Tags: javascript, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have a set of list with checkboxes, when I click 5 checkboxes an alert message to be displayed congrates you have selected 5 options. I have to do the validation using promise. If I am not using reject, it is working fine. But if I add the code as given below, 'reject' code is executed and displaying error as 'undefined'. Where have I gone wrong?

```
let clickvalidation = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][id=chk1]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      noOfClick++;
      if (noOfClick == 5) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }
  });
});

clickvalidation
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Success, You are a GEEK');
    alert(`Congrats 5 tasks have been successfully completed`);

  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
  });
```

Comment: `reject()` will reject with no error. Use something like `reject(new Error('Must select 5 tasks'))` or something of that nature

Comment: "*I have to do the validation using promise*" why? Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: it is going to 'reject' not 'resolve' why? if i omit else reject function, resolve code is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise can only resolve **once**.

The first time you change the checkbox, you call `reject()` and you don't pass it any arguments (so it errors with an `undefined` message).

Any subsequent time you change the checkbox,  you call `reject` or `resolve` but the promise is no longer pending.

---

Promises are a good tool to tell you when you have **a** result. They aren't designed to provide **multiple** results.

This isn't a situation where promises are  a useful tool. Just use a regular event handler by itself.

```js
let counter = 0;

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', () => {
  counter += 1;
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (counter === 5) {
    console.log("OK");
  } else {
    console.log("Not OK");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"><button>OK</button>
```

Comment: so if i write only resolve(), then resolve() is executed. but if i write else {reject()} then it will execute reject() function only

Comment: If you change the checkbox five times it will call `reject` four times and then `resolve` once. The first time it calls `reject` it will settle the promise. The subsequent attempts to settle the promise won't work because it is already settled.

Comment: actually this is my school assignment, and i have to do validation using promise. otherwise i am getting the output.

Comment: I don't know the specific requirements for your assignment, but you're attempting to put a square peg in a round hole. Ask whomever gave you the assignment for help — they know what you are supposed to have learned (i.e. what tools you should be using for this), they know what the actual requirements of the assignment are, they can help you better than Stackoverflow can and it is their job to do so.